# What can we infer about the gradient of multivariable Lipschitz function?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f$ be a real-valued function at $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we state that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous at $x$ if there exists a constant $C$ such that :
$$
\|f(y)-f(x)\|\leqslant C\|y-x\| 
$$
for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$ which is sufficiently near $x$.

We can rewrite the equation above to be :
$$
\|\nabla f\|\triangleq\frac{\|f(y)-f(x)\|}{\|y-x\| }\leqslant C
$$
My question is: For a several variable Lipschitz function $f$ at $\mathbb{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ if there exists a constant $L$ such that :
$$
\frac{\|f(\mathbf{y})-f(\mathbf{x})\|}{\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\| }\leqslant L
$$
can we simply acknowledge that :
$$
\frac{\|f(\mathbf{y})-f(\mathbf{x})\|}{\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\| }\qquad\text{is}\qquad \|\nabla f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\|\;?\tag{1}
$$
where $\|.\|$ can be any norm (I will consider $L_{2}$ norm).

Comment: Some general remarks: A Lipschitz-continuous function must not be differentiable on $S$. In that case the gradient doesn't exist (at least everywhere on $S$.) Also the $y$ does not need to be sufficiently near $x$, but it must hold for all $x,y \in S$. Also the last statement doesn't make much sense, since the left term still depends on $x$ and $y$, while the right hand side doesn't. Also it doesn't make sense to take the $L_2$ norm of a vector, and in general, $\nabla f$ (if it exists) must not be $L^2$. So you need to get clarity on what norm you actually want here!

Comment: I agree with your remarks and assertions, the infos I may have made my question a bit vague, but in general, is the statement made in $(1)$ correct? Or is it true provided that the gradient must not be L_{2}$? @hal4math

Comment: (1) still doesn't make much sense. Why would $\grad f$ have to inputs? Maybe try to understand the single variable case. Already there this false. Also maybe start by reading this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties). There you already get a lot of information.